# Scroll event being called after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can have a page that's very long and most of the HTML is being generated through an ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '_estimate_table_categories.php',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#estimate_table').html(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("An error has occurred. "+ textStatus);
    }
});
```

Users make changes to the data that is loaded form that ajax called through many different ways and after every change, I call a function that loads the ajax above. Normally this will load seamlessly and the user knows no different but their updates changes appear. This works fine and the application has been running for several months.

The problem is, sometimes, a scroll event is fire and it scrolls the user up. This happens randomly when a user is changing something. I have been able to make it happy but it is so sporadic.

I did a couple captures so I could see what is happening.

Here is what should happen:

[image: Correct ajax call]

Here is what randomly happens:

[image: Ajax called with random scroll event]

Here is that scroll event broken out:

[image: broken out scroll event]

The data that is being loaded is tables (kind of like long reports). The only time that I have seen this happen is when a user is adding or removing a row of data from the table. I have never seen this happen when a user is altering existing data in the tables.

As you can see, in my second image there is a scroll event and I can't for the life of me figure out where it's coming from. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what function your are calling on adding and removing of row. You might be calling some function that changes focus / trigger the event.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I am not adding or removing a row. I am regenerating the whole entire table.